# Соединение двух разных таблиц в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Возможно ли в postgresql соединить разные таблицы по такой логике: есть таблица "животные" и есть таблица "вольеры" (вольеров может быть меньше) (таблицы состоят из полей id и name)

Как создать таблицу, в которой будет распределение животных по вольерам (случайное, главное не засунуть двух животных в один вольер).

SELECT атрибутов из разных таблиц дает всевозможные сочетания, что никак не помогает. Группировкой по одному из полей получается либо "одно животное во всех вольерах", либо "все животные  в одном вольере".

Думал еще над попыткой пронумеровать (ввести столбец в каждый селект) и join-ить по номеру строки. Но не вышлo: select ... row_number() over() as  animal_row_num и такой же select с row_number() over() as cage_row_num и потом join on cage_row_num = animal_row_num  не помогает.

Подскажите, возможно ли как-то разрешить такой кейс?

UPD:
Структура таблицы

```
create table animal (id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into animal (id, name) values (1, 'cat');
insert into animal (id, name) values (2, 'dog');
insert into animal (id, name) values (3, 'bird'); 

create table cage (id integer, name varchar(100)); 
insert into cage (id, name) values (1, 'cage1'); 
insert into cage (id, name) values (2, 'cage2'); 
insert into cage (id, name) values (3, 'cage3');
```

Запрос пытаюсь составить

```
select animal.name, row_number() over() as animal_row_number 
from animal JOIN (select cage.name, row_number() over() as cage_row_number from cage) tbl join on cage_row_number = animal_row_number
```

Но он ругается на то, что имеется синтаксическая ошибка около ON. Понять не могу как обратиться к ROW_NUMBER() полученного внутри каждого select. К сожалению, гугл не помог в этом вопросе(

UPD: Спасибо Akina,
получено:

```
select animal_name, cage_name from 
(select animal.name as animal_name, row_number() over() as animal_row_number from animal) tbl1
JOIN (select cage.name as cage_name, row_number() over() as cage_row_number from cage) tbl2 on tbl2.cage_row_number = tbl1.animal_row_number
```

Comment: *Думал еще над попыткой пронумеровать* Подход правильный. Можно ещё добавить в окно ORDER BY RAND(). *не помогает* Причина? показывайте: исходные данные (create table + insert into), запрос, его результат, пояснения, что не устраивает и почему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте факты в текст вопроса (ссылка "Править" под ним) - в комментариях всё это совершенно нечитаемо.

Comment: *Понять не могу как обратиться к ROW_NUMBER() полученного внутри каждого селекта.* Вы плохо понимаете работу оконных функций. Их значение вычисляется после HAVING - так что в момент выполнения соединения таблиц и обработки ON этих значений просто не существует. Надо обе таблицы нумеровать в подзапросах (а лучше в CTE), а во внешнем запросе уже связывать.

Comment: Спасибо, осознал. Не подскажете, как научиться такие вещи осознавать: что и когда происходит? Только с опытом приходит или есть специфические темы для изучения?
В курсе баз данных в универе, к сожалению, об этом не говорили.

Comment: Документация + опыт. Причём опыт решения практических задач - простых, но много. Например, помощь в форумах или просто попытка решить чей-то несложный вопрос и последующее сравнение с принятым ответом (плюс разбор различий) - самое оно.

Answer (score 0):

```
select animal_name, cage_name from 
(select animal.name as animal_name, row_number() over() as animal_row_number from animal) tbl1
JOIN (select cage.name as cage_name, row_number() over() as cage_row_number from cage) tbl2 on tbl2.cage_row_number = tbl1.animal_row_number
```

Спасибо Akina за помощь.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).